# getting dynamic id name with jQuery

Tags: jquery

In this this jQuery script I'd like to grab the id for `$("#rowDate1")` dynamically:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       $("#rowDate1").click(function() {
           var thetext = $(this).html();
           $(this).html('<input type="text" name="edittext" id="edittext" value="'+thetext+'" />');
       });
    });
</script>
```

I'm making an inline editable table, and I only want to allow the user to click on `<td>`'s with an id. How can I do this and only allow the `<td>` ids to be clickable?

EDIT - HTML added:

```
<td id="rowDate1">09/10/12 - 09/14/12</td>
```

Comment: can we get some html as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `attribute starts with` selector:

```
$("td[id^=rowDate]").click(function() {
   // ...     
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't have two IDs named the same so you may want to use classes. You can do

```
$('#rowData').click(function() {
if($(this).attr("id") === "edittext"){
Do something }
```

or only write it for the classes.

```
$('.edittext').click(function(){
do soemthing }
```

Comment: Hi Alex. the id's are dynamically generated in php. So, it would be `rowDate1` `rowDate2` etc.

Comment: You could still give them all the same class and use that as the selector. class="<? echo $class; ?>"

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
  $("td[id]").click(function(){
    //Do something;
  });
```

This will only be called for td with id

Answer (score 3):

I'd assign each editable `td` a class and then assign a click event to each of them instead of going through your items by id:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="clickable">1</td>
        <td class="clickable">2</td>
        <td class="clickable">3</td>
        <td class="clickable">4</td>
    </tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JS:

```
$('.clickable').click(function(){
    $('.clickable').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mzaZ7/3/)
​

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to select only elements with an id by using [id] in the selector string.

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/9S8qj/) for you as an example.

So your code should look like so:

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $("td[id]").click(function() {
       var thetext = $(this).html();
       $(this).html('<input type="text" name="edittext" id="edittext" value="'+thetext+'" />');
   });
});
</script>
```